# How do we evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x-c}{x+c}\right)^x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{x-c}{x+c})^x=\frac{1}{4}$

My teacher did the following steps:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln{(\frac{x-c}{x+c})^x}=\ln{\frac{1}{4}}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln{\frac{x-c}{x+c}}=\ln{\frac{1}{4}}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x[\ln{(x-c)}-\ln{(x+c)}]=\ln{\frac{1}{4}}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln{(x-c)}-x\ln{(x+c)}=\ln{\frac{1}{4}}$

As $x\to\infty, f(x)\to\infty\cdot\infty-\infty\cdot\infty=\infty-\infty$

Then, she did this:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln{(x-c)}}{\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{\ln{(x+c)}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\ln{\frac{1}{4}}$

At this point, $f(x)\to\frac{\infty}{0}-\frac{\infty}{0}$

But she did L'Hopital's rule here, and when I said you can only do L'Hopital when $f(x)\to\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, and not when $f(x)\to\frac{\infty}{0}$ she insisted that she was doing the problem correctly. She ended up getting the right answer, but the steps were confusing to me and when I tried to solve it myself, I kept getting stuck.

Can someone please solve the problem step by step and help me out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you need to keep the two pieces together. So $\ln\frac{x-c}{x+c}$ tends to $\ln 1 = 0$. Then you have $0/0$ which, as you rightly say, is what you need.

Comment: It's not true for all $c$...did you have a particular value of $c$ in mind?

Answer (score 3):

We know that as $x \to \infty$, $\ln(x-c) - \ln(x+c) \to 0$, because it is equal to $\ln\frac{x-c}{x+c}$, which tends to $\ln 1 = 0$. Therefore we can apply L'Hopital's rule to
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln (x-c) - \ln(x+c)}{1/x}$$ even though  could not apply it to either $\frac{\ln(x-c)}{1/x}$ or $\frac{\ln(x+c)}{1/x}$ individually. Then we get $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1/(x-c) - 1/(x+c)}{-1/x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} -\frac{2cx^2}{x^2-c^2} = -2c,$$ which we can set equal to $\ln \frac14$ to solve for $c$.

This looks a lot like we got away with applying L'Hopital's rule to the $\frac{\infty}{0}$ terms, but we could only do it because their difference has the form $\frac 00$. (But if you aren't quite following what's going on, or this detail is not explained, that's very confusing!)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably fix some value of $c$, as mentioned in the comments. As per the application of the L'Hopital rule:

In your third line, you have
$$x[ {\log(x-c)-\log(x+c)}].$$
Rewrite this to
$$\frac{\log(x-c)-\log(x+c)}{1/x}.$$
Now, if $x \to \infty$, then both numerator and denominator tend to $0$. So you can apply L'Hopital here, and that should give you the answer. It's a minor thing your teacher missed, or perhaps she skipped over it for
pedagogical purposes, so don't think badly of her.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that, you can *also* reach the solution without applying the L'Hôpital's rule :

$$
\small{\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x-c}{x+c}\right)^x&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-\frac {2c}{x+c}\right)^x\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac {x+c}{2c}}\right)^{\frac {x+c}{2c}}\right)^{\frac {2cx}{x+c}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac {x+c}{2c}}\right)^{\frac {x+c}{2c}}\right)^{\frac {2c}{1+\frac cx}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac {x+c}{2c}}\right)^{\frac {x+c}{2c}}\right)^{\lim_{x\to \infty} {\frac {2c}{1+\frac cx}}}\\
&=e^{-2c}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}}
$$

---

Here, I assume that the question is about :

> Find the real number $c$, such that :
>
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x-c}{x+c}\right)^x=\frac 14 $$
>
> holds .

If so, the answer becomes :

$$
\begin{align}e^{-2c}&=\frac 14\\
-2c&=-2\ln 2\\
c&=\ln 2\thinspace \thinspace . \end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice answer, mine is basically the same as yours but written differently (I used substitution and simple asymptotics to utilize the limit definition of the exponential function while you algebraically manipulate the expression).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve this without L'Hopital. We know that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=e$$or$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac tx\right)^x=e^t$$ (make the substitution $x\mapsto x/t$). Replace $t$ with $-2c$: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac {2c}x\right)^x=e^{-2c}$$The limit in question can be re-written as $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac {2c}{x+c}\right)^x$$and since $x\sim x+c$, the limits are equivalent. So $$e^{-2c}=\frac14\implies c=\ln 2$$